# How to perform data sampling with a specific frequency using SQL

Tags: sql, hive, impala

I have a table which has some values with a Unix timestamp.

Frequency of data is variable, but it is generally around one data point per minute.
I would like to perform a sampling of the data without aggregation, with a custom frequency settings. For instance, I would like to obtain a maximum of one data point per 15 Minutes.

This is an example:

```
row dt              dt_parsed           value
1   1684449236166   2023-05-18 22:33    241.0
2   1684449854529   2023-05-18 22:44    240.0
3   1684450070779   2023-05-18 22:47    240.0
4   1684450684766   2023-05-18 22:58    241.0
5   1684450868360   2023-05-18 23:01    241.0
6   1684451027112   2023-05-18 23:03    241.0
7   1684452361787   2023-05-18 23:26    241.0
```

What I would like to obtain, considering 15 Minutes as frequency:

```
row dt              dt_parsed           value
1   1684449236166   2023-05-18 22:33    241.0 --> nearest point to 22:30
2   1684449854529   2023-05-18 22:44    240.0 --> nearest point to 22:45
5   1684450868360   2023-05-18 23:01    241.0 --> nearest point to 23:00
6   1684451027112   2023-05-18 23:03    241.0 --> nearest point to 23:15
7   1684452361787   2023-05-18 23:26    241.0 --> nearest point to 23:30
```

I'm using Impala/Hive to query the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `floor()` function to round the Unix timestamps to the nearest desired time interval:

```
SELECT
  row,
  dt,
  dt_parsed,
  value
FROM
  your_table
WHERE
  dt IN (
    SELECT
      dt
    FROM (
      SELECT
        dt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY floor(dt / (15 * 60 * 1000)) ORDER BY dt) AS row_number
      FROM
        your_table
    ) subquery
    WHERE
      row_number = 1
  )
ORDER BY
  dt;
```